# accessing and saving a timestamp outside of a function

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

a little bit new with swift just had a quick inquiry when dealing with timestamps.

What i have is an app i am wrking on that when a button is pressed, the time is displayed; this happens on each of the 3 buttons. That is set up fine, what i would like to do is have swift be able to access each of those times so i could then display a label which will tell the discrepancy between each time. ( ie endtime - starttime is equal to ). everything is set up besides being able to access those timestamps that are within the button pressed functions.

I know this is probly a pretty generic / basic question thx for any insights on this swift solution

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: please add code on what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by 'timestamp' you're referring to the Date struct (which is most commonly used for this purpose). If you press command + shift + 0, in Xcode, you will be taken to the documentation where you do a search and see all the various functions you can call on Date to do whatever you want with it.

The function you appear to be interested in is

```
func timeIntervalSince(_ date: Date) -> TimeInterval
```

you'd use it like this

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date()
print(date1.timeIntervalSince(date2))
```

Comment: hey thx so much sam ! will try that out asap and see how it goes that does make sense using that struct!